# Как войти в аккаунт с Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

подскажите пожалуйста как войти в аккаут гугла?Вводит логин,потом выскакивает на переход к паролю:

Возможно, этот браузер или приложение небезопасны. Подробнее…
Попробуйте сменить браузер. Если вы уже используете поддерживаемый браузер, повторите попытку входа ещё раз.

Стоит:
selenium=3.141.0

Как решить эту проблему?Заранее благодарен

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager

import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://accounts.google.com/InteractiveLogin/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&ec=GAZAmgQ&hl=ru&passive=true&ifkv=AQMjQ7Qf7QofAlTbU0ycpGrT8pgUsg6qR95uTnFONH2PzMmbAdEEmGhLtud8ziT_wo95zBn6kV-Fww&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opera_profile = r"path_opera"

options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + opera_profile)
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")

options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")

options.add_argument("--incognito")

options.add_argument("user_agent=DN")
options._binary_location = r'my_path'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install())
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get(url=url)
GMAIL = 'email'
PASSWORD = 'password'

driver.find_element(By.ID, "identifierId").send_keys(GMAIL)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(
    PASSWORD)
driver.find_element(By.NAME,
                    "password").send_keys(
    Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10000)
```

Comment: Присоединяюсь. Мне в свое время не помог ни undetected_chromedriver со всевозможными вариациями ни geckodriver для firefox. Хотя, может, просто я не до конца разобрался.